How to Pivot Column to Row in MicroStrategy Developer
This is the table that I have



Contract_ID
Period
Forecast
Shortfall




1
May23
35325
456


2
June24
3466
768


3
Sept22
457657
879



I need the output as:



Contract_ID
May23Forecast
May23Shortfall
June24Forecast
June24Shortfall
Sept22Forecast
Sept22Shortfall
Total Forecast
Total Shortfall




1
35325
456




35325
456


2


3466
768


3466
768


3




457657
879
457657
879



In MicroStrategy Developer.
I'm able to achieve this by placing the period attribute on the row level for forecast but I'm not able to add another metric after that.
Any suggestions, anyone?

So,  (Not a MicroStrategy Specific Answer)
That said, I always believe that locating business logic closer to the database has benefits.
--If you know the periods (If they are fixed this is easy)
SELECT 
,   Contract_ID
,   CASE WHEN PERIOD = 'May23'
         THEN Forecast
         ELSE NULL
    END AS May23Forecast
,   CASE WHEN PERIOD = 'May23'
         THEN Shortfall
         ELSE NULL
    END AS May23Shortfall
,   CASE WHEN PERIOD = 'June24'
         THEN Forecast
         ELSE NULL
    END AS June24Forecast
,   CASE WHEN PERIOD = 'June24'
         THEN Shortfall
         ELSE NULL
    END AS June24Shortfall
...
FROM YOURTABLE
;

Etc.
-- IF you are not certain what periods their are, but you know how many (Say 12 a year) something like this can be done
SELECT 
    Contract_ID
,   Period
,   MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD_COUNTER = 1
         THEN Forecast
         ELSE NULL
    END) AS FORCASt1
,   MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD_COUNTER = 1
         THEN Shortfall
         ELSE NULL
    END) AS Shortfall1
,   MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD_COUNTER = 2
         THEN Forecast
         ELSE NULL
    END) AS FORCASt1
,   MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD_COUNTER = 2
         THEN Shortfall
         ELSE NULL
    END) AS Shortfall1
...
FROM YOURTABLE
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 
    PERIOD
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PERIOD) AS PERIOD_COUNTER
FROM YOUR TABLE
GROUP BY 1
)
;


thank you for your input. Can you also help me to understand how I can calculate total_shortfall and total_forecast row wise?

Instead of:
,   MAX(CASE WHEN PERIOD_COUNTER = 1
THEN Shortfall
ELSE NULL
END) AS Shortfall1
USE:
,   SUM(CASE WHEN PERIOD_COUNTER = 1
THEN Shortfall
ELSE 0
END) AS Shortfall1
